# modify div style on .toggle - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an image with id `mainimage`. It has a styling to limit width and height by setting `max-width:100%` and `max-height:100%`. But I want to remove it on the first instance of my script

```
$(document).ready( function() {
var hjkl = $("#mainimage").height();
var hjklw = $("#mainimage").width();
$('#logo').toggle(
function() {
    $('#mainimage').animate({"width": 1600, "height": 1200}, "fast");
}, function() {
    $('#mainimage').animate({"width": hjklw, "height": hjkl}, "fast");
})
});
```

How can i do this??

Thanks in advance...`:)`

blasteralfred

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do something the first time the logo is clicked, you can do this:

```
var hjkl = $("#mainimage").height();
var hjklw = $("#mainimage").width();
$('#logo')
  .one('click', function(){ 
    /* your one-time stuff */
    $("#mainimage").css({ 'max-height':'','max-width':''});
  })
  .toggle(
    function() {
      $('#mainimage').animate({"width": 1600, "height": 1200}, "fast");
    }, function() {
      $('#mainimage').animate({"width": hjklw, "height": hjkl}, "fast");
  });
```

It might be easier to apply your one-time styles with a class, and then remove them with `.removeClass` in the one-time section.

Comment: how can i remove max-width and max-height??